# How to a write a subsidies contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, remix, smart-contract-wallets

I am new to solidity and Trying to wrapper my brain around it;

I have being Writing this contact but, I am getting an error , cannot able to Store variable in contract.

Function of contracts:-

_dbs2.sol:
  when Get_data function is call it give array as output. 
  get_data() >> gets ration_id from map>> get data from owner_detail and return an array to sa_2.sol.
 sa_2.sol:
 After calling Get_data function the return an array.
       
After getting the array, it verify it with rqureiment.
       
After verification is succesful it give a disscount on the amount send by the sender.       Return the extra amount back to the sender.

_dbs2.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Get_data {
mapping(address => uint) public ration_id;
mapping(uint256 => owner_details) public owner_detail;



function set1(address _addr, uint _i) public {
    ration_id[_addr] = _i;
}

function set_rid() public {
    set1(0xDEE7796E89C82C36BAdd1375076f39D69FafE252, 1); // fake address
    set1(0xDEE7796E89C82C36BAdd1375076f19D69FafE253, 2); // fake address
    set1(0xDEE7796E89C82C36BAdd1371076f39D69FafE254, 3); // fake address
}            

function Get_data(address _addr) public view returns(uint[] memory) {
    set_rid();
    uint[] memory arr;
    arr.push(owner_detail[ ration_id[_addr]].colorcode);
    arr.push(owner_detail[ ration_id[_addr]].annual_income);

    return  arr;
}

struct owner_details {
    string name;
    string gender;
    uint8 colorcode;
    uint256 annual_income;
}

function od_dir() public {
    var add_d;
   // constructor() {
    //JHON
    add_d = owner_detail[1];
    add_d.name = "John";
    add_d.gender = "male";
    add_d.colorcode = 1; // Y = 1 , O = 2 , W = 3
    add_d.annual_income = 50000;
    
    //SAM
    add_d = owner_detail[2];
    add_d.name = "sam";
    add_d.gender = "female";
    add_d.colorcode = 2; // Y = 1 , O = 2 , W = 3
    add_d.annual_income = 120000;
    
    //JASMIN
    add_d = owner_detail[3];
    add_d.name = "Jasmin";
    add_d.gender = "female";
    add_d.colorcode = 3; // Y = 1 , O = 2 , W = 3
    add_d.annual_income = 500000;
  //  }
}   
}
```

sa_2.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;


import "./_dbs2.sol";


contract FundingAggrement {
uint recivered_amonunt;
uint amonunt;
uint[] a;
address owner;  

function validityCheck() public view returns(uint) {
    owner = msg.sender;
    Interface_gd gd = Interface_gd();
    a = require(gd.get(owner));
    require(a[0] == 1 || a[0] == 2);
    if(a[0] == 1) {
       require(a[1]<=50000);
    }
    if(a[0] == 2) {
       require(a[1]<=120000);
    }
    return a[0];
}

function aws(string _product_id, uint _ant) public view returns(uint) {
    uint amount;
    uint[] b;
    b = validityCheck();
    if(a[0] == 2) {
      if(_product_id == 'Fuel') {
        amount = _ant * (45/100);
      }
      if(_product_id == 'Food') {
        amount = _ant * (45/100);
      }
    }
    if(a[0] == 1) {
       if(_product_id == 'Fuel') {
        amount = _ant * (50/100);
      }
      if(_product_id == 'Food') {
        amount = _ant * (50/100);
      }
      if(_product_id == 'Electricity') {
        amount = _ant * (45/100);
      }
    }
    return amount;
}

function getRefund(string _product_id) public returns(bool success){
    recivered_amonunt == msg.value;
    amount = aws(_product_id, recivered_amonunt);
    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    return true;
}

function FundingAggrement(string _product_id) public returns(string){
    getRefund(_product_id);
    return 'Sccessfull Transfer';
}
```

}

Comment: Can you simplify the contracts? It is quite hard to try to follow it. Sometimes while simplifying the error is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your contract, I see you have an issue in your Get_data function. Dynamic arrays cannot be stored in memory and must be stored in Storage. Storage variable cannot be defined within function so in your case you may opt for fixed-sized arrays, which can be stored in memory (but does not push array.push() method).

This should fix your variable storage error.